# looping using window.requestAnimateFrame

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a working piece of code from setInterval to RAF.

I can get it to work on the first pass, however, I cannot seem to find a way for it to loop. I can reset the elapsed variable and reset the gradient, I was expecting this to enact the else part of the loop?

```html
  <div id='test' style='height: 10vh;'>hi</div>
  <script>
  var adiv = document.getElementById('test')
  let start; 
  function animate(timestamp) {
    if (start === undefined) {
      start = timestamp;
    }
    let elapsed = timestamp - start;
    let f = Math.min(0.0335 * elapsed, 100);
    if (elapsed > 3000) {
      elapsed = 0;
      adiv.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, aqua)`;
    } else {
      adiv.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right, white ${f}%, aqua)`;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have defined but not initialised your variable `f`. The section of code that runs if `f > 100` will never run because `let f;` is equivalent to `let f = undefined;` If you want it to loop, you need to either pull `let f` outside the function `animate` and make it a global variable, or you need to initialise `f`. Using the second approach your code could be written as below:

```html
<div id='test' style='height: 10vh;'>hi</div>
<script>
  var adiv = document.getElementById('test')
  let start; 
  function animate(timestamp) {
    if (start === undefined) {
      start = timestamp;
    }
    let elapsed = timestamp - start;
    let f = Math.min(0.0335 * elapsed, 100);
    if (f > 100) {
      console.log(`elapsed = ${elapsed} | f = ${f}`);
    } else {
      adiv.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right, white ${f}%, aqua)`
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it is most appreciated. I am struggling to get the progress bar to loop, I can reset the elapsed variable and the gradient but it does not enact the else statement which I thought would make it a loop?